# How to restart specific running python file Ubuntu

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, terminate

I have running python file "cepusender/main.py" (and another python files). How can I restart/kill only main.py file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's *a* way (there are many):

```
ps -ef | grep 'cepusender/main.py' | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill
```

- `ps` is the [process snapshot](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ps.1.html) command. `-e` prints every process on the system, and `-f` prints the full-format listing, which, germanely, includes the command line arguments of each process.
- [`grep`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/grep) prints lines matching a pattern. We first `grep` for your file, which will match both the `python` process and the `grep` process. We then `grep -v` (invert match) for `grep`, paring output down to just the `python` process.

Output now looks like the following:

```
user      77864   68024  0 13:53 pts/4    00:00:00 python file.py
```

- Next, we use [awk](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/awk.1p.html) to pull out just the second column of the output, which is the [process ID or PID](https://www.howtogeek.com/devops/what-are-unix-pids-and-how-do-they-work/).
- Finally we use [`xargs`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/xargs.1.html) to pass the PID to [`kill`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/kill), which asks the `python` process to shutdown gracefully.

Answer (score 0):

`kill` is the command to send signals to processes.

You can use `kill -9 PID` to kill your python process, where 9 is the number for **SIGKILL** and PID is the python Process ID.

Comment: @СерверЧауш - One way to obtain a (list of) process id (PID) is: `ps -ef | grep “specific_name”`